# Android: App icon is different inside "App Info"

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

So I have this Xamarin app that I'm working on. On iOS the icon(s) are displayed correctly, but on Android the icon is only correct when viewing in the application launcher. When holding down the app icon and pressing "App info" the icon displayed is this one:

[image]

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add `Icon = "@drawable/dogg"` attribute in `MainActivity` .

  ```
   [Activity(Label = "FormsApp", Icon = "@drawable/dogg", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
   public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
  ```
- Set `icon` and `roundIcon` in `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

  ```
    <application 
    android:label="FormsApp.Android" 
    android:theme="@style/MainTheme" 
    android:icon="@drawable/dogg" 
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/dogg">
  ```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful suggestion, but now the Xamarin icon is displaying instead of the android dev icon. Very weird

Comment: Delete the app from device and try again .

Comment: You know what, your example did work. I was using mipmap, didn't think it would give me such weird behaviour. Changed to drawable instead and now it works.